# How to use Lazy Adam optimizer in tensorflow 2.0.0

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, adam

This code doesnt work: it has problem with `tf.contrib`

```
model.compile(optimizer=TFOptimizer(tf.contrib.opt.LazyAdamOptimizer()), loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

I have tried something with `tensorflow_addons.optimizers.LazyAdam()` but that does not work either.

Any ideas how to run `LazyAdam` in tensorflow 2.0.0 ?

PS: only `Adam` works well as following:

```
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

Comment: Please specify "doesn't work". That is, provide a minimal, complete code example as well as a full error traceback (in case you are getting an error). Note that `contrib` does not exist in TF 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
optimizer = tfa.optimizers.LazyAdam()
```

tensorflow_addons is an extra functionality for TensorFlow 2.x, but now Tensorflow 2.x is still not very stable, if you are facing with `module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'register_keras_serializable'`, try to update you tensorflow to the latest stable version.

Comment: This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?

Comment: Hi, I got this error when trying to load tensorflow_addons: module 'tensorflow_core.keras.utils' has no attribute 'register_keras_serializable'

Comment: Okay sorry guys, seems the problem is between my pc and chair... I updated version of tensorflow (switching from R to python, not very intuitive for me TBH) and it is working now. thanks. :)